# Skype messages are pending in queue when sent from java

Tags: java, skype

I am trying to send Skype messages with skype-java-api. All messages sent in this way are staying in sending state and never actually getting sent. I can see the messages but all are with loading logo beside them. However, when I sent message normally from Skype, it is getting sent.

Comment: From the skype-java-api github page: "According with issue #81, the chat support already stopped working."

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "skype-java-api" is reaching (or has) it's end of life.

From the [github page](https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api)

> Important: Desktop API is crippled now
>
> As time passes, this project becomes less and less relevant due to
>   Desktop API discontinuation.

**and even more important**

> According with issue #81, the chat support already stopped working.

It appears that this is what you encountered.