# Sending skype messages programmatically

Tags: java, skype

I tried to do this with skype-java-api and also Skype4Java but in both cases messages are queued in sending state and are never sent. I see that desktop API is crippled now. 
So, is there any workaround?

This is my piece of code:

```
for(Chat c : Skype.getAllChats()) {
    if(c.getId().contains("someUser")) {
        Hehehehe hehe = new Hehehehe();
        hehe.send(c);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: skype-api works, just read carefully how to use it.

Comment: can u put what u try to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skype messages are pending in queue when sent from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413040/skype-messages-are-pending-in-queue-when-sent-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

There's **no workaround** for sending chat messages using skype-java-api.

---

The Skype Desktop API, which skype-java-api is using, no longer supports sending chat messages:

> **Important:** As communicated in this blog post, due to technology improvements we are making to the Skype experience, some features of the API will stop working with Skype for desktop. For example, delivery of chat messages using the API will cease to work.

Source: [What is the Desktop API?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA214/what-is-the-desktop-api)

There are multiple tickets on the skype-java-api issue tracker ([1](https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api/issues/78), [2](https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api/issues/81)) regarding this issue and the developer has stated that he'll [stop supporting his project](https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api#important-desktop-api-is-crippled-now) and that skype-java-api can [no longer send chat messages](https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api/issues/81#issuecomment-246151982):

> So, what you are witnessing now is precisely what they already announced. Therefore, this is not an issue of the api, but simply the fact that skype is dropping down support for message delivery